# Push Notification after resign an iPhone application

Tags: iphone, push-notification

I am wondering to know how to use command line to resign an application (with push notification) correctly.

Here are some background:

- My original application works well with Push Notification.
- If I resign the application via "Organizer -> Archives -> Share"
  with any developer cert, Push notification still works
- If I resign the application via command line `codesign -f -s "iPhone Distribution: *****" -vv path/to/app`, the app still works well. However, push notification stop working with message `No valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application 'MyPushTest': (null). Notifications will not be delivered.`

Is there anybody know how to use command line do a correct resign, after which push notification will work as normal?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If your mobileprovisioning profile will allow push notifications - everything should run smoothly. Please note - wildcard mobileprovisioning profiles does not support push notifications.

To check if mobileprovisioning is compatible with push notifications - check "aps-environment" string presence in the profile. It should be set to "development" for Sandbox and "production" for Production gateway.

You might want to check [www.aironapp.com](http://www.aironapp.com). It does the recodesigning for you. You will need to configure Apple Dev Account in the settings.